# How to find MySQl query type before query execution Zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am using Zend Framework with MySQL DB as backend.

I want to perform some operations depending on the type of query executed on MySQL server.

I want to perform these operations before query execution.

So my question is can I find the type of query before it is executed using Zend Framework e.g. SELECT , UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "before it is executed" ? When exactly would that be?

Comment: Hi Pekka! Before execution means if you are using $this->getDbTable()->insert($data) in your DbMapperClass then before these insertion happens I should be able to know the type of query i.e. INSERT, same way if you are using $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll() then I should be able to know the type of query i.e. SELECT. Am I clear ?

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look at the code of this class - Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

Location - Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php

Whenever I am into doubts about how Zend Framework is executing something, I dig inside the framework and check the code executing in the underlying classes.

Its clears up every question I have in my mind.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I wll try looking into the granular details of this file. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: It didnt help ---------------- Anyone listening? Can anyone help me with this ?